# Counting number of skipped files in batch copy

Tags: batch-file

I have made a short batch to copy my music to my car-USB

```
@echo off

set OLDDIR=%CD%

set /a UPCOUNT=0
set /a TOTALCOUNT=0

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

cd /d E:\Music
   for /r %%a in (*.m4a) do (
     set /a TOTALCOUNT=!TOTALCOUNT!+1
   )

   for /r %%a in (*.m4a) do (
     echo n | COPY/-y "%%a" %OLDDIR%
     set /a UPCOUNT=!UPCOUNT!+1 
     cls
     echo !UPCOUNT! / !TOTALCOUNT!
   )

endlocal
```

It is working fine but I would also like to find out how many files were skipped by

```
     echo n | COPY/-y "%%a" %OLDDIR%
```

I tried something like

```
@echo off

set OLDDIR=%CD%

set /a UPCOUNT=0
set /a TOTALCOUNT=0
set /a DUBCOUNT=0

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

cd /d E:\Music
   for /r %%a in (*.m4a) do (
     set /a TOTALCOUNT=!TOTALCOUNT!+1
   )

   for /r %%a in (*.m4a) do (
     set copyCommand="echo n | COPY/-y "%%a" %OLDDIR%"
     for /f "tokens=1" %%b in ('%copyCommand% ^| findstr /c:"fil(er) kopieret."') do set fileCnt=%%b"
     if "!fileCnt!"==1 (set /a DUBCOUNT=!DUBCOUNT!+1)
     set /a UPCOUNT=!UPCOUNT!+1 
     cls
     echo !UPCOUNT! / !TOTALCOUNT! - !DUBCOUNT! dubs
   )

endlocal
```

Sadly not working and I am getting out of my comfort zone :-P

Any ideas?

The "fil(er) kopieret." is because my OS is Danish ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"

set /a UPCOUNT=0
set /a TOTALCOUNT=0
SET /a skipcount=0

pushd %sourcedir%
for /r %%a in (*.csv) do (
 set /a TOTALCOUNT+=1
)

for /r %%a in (*.csv) do (
 IF EXIST "%destdir%\%%~nxa" (SET /a skipcount +=1) ELSE (
  COPY "%%a" %destdir%\
  set /a UPCOUNT+=1
 )
 cls
 echo !UPCOUNT! / !TOTALCOUNT! !skipcount! skipped
)
popd

GOTO :EOF
```

I changed direcctories and filemasks to suit my system and a few techniques to suit my preferred style.

The key is the `if exist` statement to find out whether the destination file exists using the `~nx` modifiers on the metavariable `%%a` to extract the name and extension.

See `for /?` from the prompt for docco.